# Connecting athena to superset

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-athena, apache-superset

So, I am using AWS athena where I have `Data Source` set to `AwsDataCatalog`, `database` set to `test_db`, under which I have a `table` named `debaprc`.

Now, I have superset installed on an EC2 instance (in virtual environment). On the Instance, I have installed `PyAthenaJDBC` and `PyAthena`. Now, when I launch Superset and try to add a database, the syntax given is this:

`awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}`

Now I have 2 questions -

1. What do I provide for `schema_name`?
2. I tried putting `test_db` as `schema_name` but it couldn't connect for some reason. Am I doing this right or do I need to do stuff differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware [of the encoding](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/athena):

```
awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/{schema_name}?AwsRegion={region_name}&s3_staging_dir=s3%3A%2F%2Faws-athena-results-xxxxxxx
```

For example, for me it has been necessary to:

- transform `s3://` to `s3%3A%2F%2F` (and not just the `:` like in Superset doc?)
- add the region *again* in the extra parameters

If you do not provide schema name (also called database), I think it defaults to a value of `default`

Sadly when a connection string fails on Superset, nothing very helpful is displayed...

Answer (score 2):

Check PyAthena version. [Superset docs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/installing-database-drivers) tell `PyAthena>1.2.0` while [PyAthena PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/2.5.1/) says `PyAthena[SQLAlchemy]>=1.0.0, <2.0.0`. In my case `PyAthena[SQLAlchemy]>1.2.0, <2.0.0` (combining both constraints) solved an issue and the tables were present in dropdown list in SQL Lab (it was empty with `PyAthena==2.5.1` (latest) version before).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me adding port 443 to the connection string as below and you can use `test_db` as `schema_name`:

`awsathena+rest://{aws_access_key_id}:{aws_secret_access_key}@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}`